# Как сделать поле неактивным на всех этапах ввода данных

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю ToDo лист и застрял на одной доработке - нужно сделать так, что если текстовое поле пустое, нельзя нажать на кнопку "Добавить". Пытался сделать с `formButton.disabled = true`, но почему-то это срабатывает только при первом клике на кнопку, последующие разы добавить можно и пустое поле. Подскажите, как исправить?

```js
formInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    if (formInput.value.length > 0) {
        formButton.disabled = false;
    } else if (formInput.value.length < 0) {
        formButton.disabled = true;
    }
})
```

```html
<form>
            <input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Your Task">
            <button type="submit" class="form-button" disabled>
                <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
            </button>
<form>
```

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос: "последующие разы" - это какие разы? Сделайте воспроизводимый пример в спиппете (сейчас Ваш код выдаёт ошибки)

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, полный пример https://codepen.io/victorbej/pen/qBmGyWG

Comment: `formInput.value.length < 0` вместо нуля, напишите 1, либо сделайте `== 0`. Должно помочь.

Comment: Еще можно сократить до `formButton.disabled = !formInput.value.length`

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду, что после постановки одной задачи кнопка не блокируется снова, то надо просто добавить `formButton.disabled = true;` в конец функции `addTodo`

Comment: Благодарю, formButton.disabled = true нужно было добавить в addTodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const formInput = document.querySelector('.form-input')
const formButton = document.querySelector('.form-button')
const todo = document.querySelector('.todo')

formInput.oninput = ({target}) => {
  const isNeedEnable = formButton.disabled && formInput.value.length > 0
  const isNeedDisable = !formButton.disabled && formInput.value.length == 0

  if (isNeedEnable || isNeedDisable) {
    formButton.disabled = !formButton.disabled
  }
}

formButton.onclick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault() //отключаем onsubmit
  createTodoItem(formInput.value)
  //После добавления нужно очистить поле ввода и отключить кнопку.
  formInput.value = ""
  formButton.disabled = true;
}

createTodoItem = (value) => {
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.classList.add('todo-item')
  item.textContent = value;
  todo.appendChild(item)
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Your Task">
  <button type="submit" class="form-button" disabled>
    <i class="far fa-plus-square">add</i>
  </button>
<form>

<ol class="todo">
<ol>
```

Comment: К сожалению  не помогло, возникает такая же проблема https://codepen.io/victorbej/pen/qBmGyWG

Comment: Дополнил, чтобы было понятней. В вашей ф-ии addTodo, после выполнения, нужно кнопку тоже делать disabled (сейчас вы этого не делаете), т.к. эвент oninput проверяет значение поля и меняет состояние кнопки ТОЛЬКО при вводе с клавиатуры.

Comment: Благодарю, заработало